# How to publish link from iOS app to Facebook app with custom URL scheme?

Tags: ios, facebook, url-scheme

I am creating an iOS app (using Adobe AIR) and I want to put a share button to my game that will allow the player to share a link to my game. I can do it with Graph API using my app's token, but I don't want a story published by my app. I want the native Facebook app to open and bring a share dialog. All my research concluded me to use the custom URL scheme such as `fb://publish/?text=my_text` but I couldn't get it working. I tried typing exactly that in Safari, it brings the native Facebook app, but no publish dialog or anything. All the sources online tells this, but it is not working. What could I be possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Should be fp[APP_ID]:// where you configure your URL scheme according to Step 2 of http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-appid-across-multiple-apps-ios-sdk/

Comment: actually i'm trying the other way around: publishing to facebook from app, NOT opening my app from facebook or url.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question.  Do another fb:// style URLs work? - http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook

Comment: nope, they don't work. anything that starts with `fb://` DOES open the facebook app, but it doesn't navigate to anywhere, it just opens and stays where i've left it off last time